# What is the difference between *ptr and *ptr.get() when using auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

Why would I use `get()` with `*`, instead of just calling `*`?

Consider the following code:

```
auto_ptr<int> p (new int);
*p = 100;
cout << "p points to " << *p << '\n';           //100

auto_ptr<int> p (new int);
*p.get() = 100;
cout << "p points to " << *p.get() << '\n'; //100
```

Result is exactly the same. Is `get()` more secure?

Comment: practically no difference.

Comment: As this is tagged C++11: `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated and will be removed in C++17. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: "Is get() more secure?" Using `auto_ptr` makes your whole code insecure in my opinion. Don't use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Practically no difference.

In case of `*p`, the overloaded `operator*` (defined by `auto_ptr`) is invoked which returns the *reference* to the underlying object (after dereferencing it — which is done by the member function). In the latter case, however, `p.get()` returns the underlying pointer which you dereference yourself.

I hope that answers your question. Now I'd advise you to **avoid** using `std::auto_ptr`, as it is badly designed  — it has even been deprecated, in preference to other smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` (along with  `std::weak_ptr`).

Answer (score 6):

`*p` calls [`auto_ptr::operator*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/operator*), which dereferences the managed pointer.

`*p.get` first calls method [`auto_ptr::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/get), which returns the managed pointer, which is then dereferenced by operator `*`.

These will provide exactly the same result once executed: the managed pointer is dereferenced, and there will be no additional checking when using `get`.

Note that `auto_ptr` is deprecated since C++11. It is dangerous because ownership of the pointer is transfered when copying:

```
std::auto_ptr<int> p(new int(42));

{
    std::auto_ptr<int> copy_of_p(p); // ownership of *p is transfered here
} // copy_of_p is destroyed, and deletes its owned pointer

// p is now a dangling pointer
```

To avoid the problem, you had to "manage the managed pointers":

```
std::auto_ptr<int> p(new int(42));

{
    std::auto_ptr<int> copy_of_p(p); // ownership of *p is transfered here

    // ...

    p = copy_of_p; // p gets back ownership
} // copy_of_p is destroyed, but doesn't delete pointer owned by p

// p is still valid
```

Use [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead.

Answer (score 4):

There is no effective difference. `operator*` is defined to return `*get()` ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/operator*)).

You should consider using [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in `auto_ptr`'s stead. The latter has been removed from the current C++ standard and has very non-intuitive yank-on-copy behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `get()` on a smart pointer (regardless of auto_, unique_, shared_, or otherwise).  This returns a naked pointer that isn't under the control of an RAII class.  This opens up various possibilities of giving the pointer to another RAII class (causing double-deletion later), or the caller doing something silly like deleting the pointer (again causing double-deletion).  Just dereference the smart pointer.

PS: For experts only: Yes, there are other legitimate reasons for extracting the raw pointer from a smart pointer.  But by not using get() in general, the times that it is used becomes a red flag for "there's something funky going on here, pay attention!".